# Get a Twilio plugin to load

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Twilio Plugin downloaded but not loaded

I followed this tutorial, on chat transfer,
and all the steps work fine. except the actual transfer button does not appear
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/solutions-library/chat-and-sms-transfers

Looking a the status report the chat transfer plugin is downloaded ok but not loaded like the rest of the plugins.  The sample plugin from the tutorial loads fine and I am using the same deploy/release steps https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin

> 9:28:24 AM | log | plugin plugin-chat-sms-transfer correctly downloaded from https://flex.twilio.com/plugins/v1/plugin-chat-sms-transfer/18.0.0/bundle.js?releaseSid=FK5f557ec19f63b49446efb26cbcd
> 9:28:24 AM | log | loading plugin plugin-hb-patient-profile function HbPatientProfilePlugin(){return _classCallCheck(this,HbPatientProfilePlugin),t.call(this,"HbPatientProfilePlugin")}
> 9:28:24 AM | log | loading HbPatientProfilePlugin@0.0.1 plugin

What might be causing a plugin not to load? there is no obvious error in the developer console output. Is there some other source that might give better errors?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the console view was showing an error. And the error eventually lead to an import problem in the code. specifically index.js in src needed to import * all the functions in Twilio plugin.